# Swiper in Nextjs with Thumbnails types error

Tags: typescript, next.js, swiper.js

While implementing Swiper with Next.js, I encountered a problem related to thumbnails.

```
"onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}"
```

returns me a Typescript error:

```
swiper-react.d.ts(23, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onSwiper' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

I tried changing types for

```
const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);
```

however, that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Anybody can help me?
I apologize for my behavior, but I care strongly about this :(

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue with:

```
import { type Swiper as SwiperTypes, FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs } from "swiper";
```

next, I create const for thumbs:

```
const [swiperInstance, setSwiperInstance] = useState<SwiperTypes | null>(null);
```

next I set this props:

```
thumbs={{ swiper: swiperInstance }}
```

and in thumbs:

```
 onSwiper={setSwiperInstance}
```